# Easy and Smart Amounts String/int using java

Tags: java

Basically I am working with a game, so I want an easy way to identify items amounts..

for Example I am creating an `ArrayList<Item>();` and I am identifying the items like:

```
//Item(itemId, itemAmount);
new Item(ItemsList.COINS, 1_000_000);//this is 1m of coins
new Item(ItemsList.FISH, 2000);//this is 2k of fish
```

I want an easier way instead of writing the amounts to be like

```
new Item(ItemsList.COINS, Amounts.1M);
new Item(ItemsList.FISH, Amounts.2k);`
```

like this, I want guide on how do I create the class Amounts and go on about it?

Of course I am not going to be creating an enum with all values like what's the smart way of doing this task. Please help me thanks!

Comment: what you are asking is just enums

Comment: The names of enum constants cannot start with a number so it wouldn't work anyway.

Comment: IMO, the truly smart way to do it is to not do it at all.  Suffixes like K and M are ambiguous.  (If the Java designers thought this kind of thing was a good idea, they would have included in the language syntax.  I can't think of *any* mainstream programming language that supports scaling suffixes ... other than standard E (scientific) notation.)

Comment: Anyhow, I don't think there is a way to do this that is any sense "easy" or "smart".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try something like this:

```
class Amounts {

    public static int k(int amount){
        return amount * 1_000;
    }
    
    public static int M(int amount){
        return amount * 1_000_000;
    }
    
    (...)
}
```

And then you could use it like this:

```
new Item(ItemList.COINS, Amounts.M(1));
new Item(ItemList.FISH, Amounts.k(2));
```

However, I personally prefer just using constants (and inserting `_` after three digits) like:

```
new Item(ItemList.COINS, 1_000_000);
```

Or something like

```
new Item(ItemList.COINS, 1 * Amounts.MILLION);
```

(and define a static constant `public static int MILLION = 1_000_000;` in class `Amounts`)

Comment: Well the OP could do that, but overall I don't think they will improve their code by doing that.  And besides, there is the small problem that in some contexts "k" means 1024 rather than 1000.  So using "k" as short-hand in your code ... and in your written communications in general ... is potentially ambiguous.  When you are talking to human beings, they will typically disambiguate from the context.  But compilers are not that smart.

Comment: This wont work, if he has to use numbers like 1.5k,2.3m.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below function to convert number into your format and can use in your code with some changes as per your requirement -

```
    public static String formatNumber(double value) {
    String suf = " kmbt";
    NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###.#");

    int power = (int)StrictMath.log10(value);
    value = value/(Math.pow(10,(power/3)*3));
    String result =formatter.format(value);
    result  = result  + suf.charAt(power/3);
    return result .length()>4 ?  result .replaceAll("\\.[0-9]+", "") : result ;
}
```